# How to upload image with Strapi.io and AngularJS?

Tags: node.js, json, angular6, postman, strapi

I have a type of http.post that has to be via Curl, type this example:

```
curl -X POST -F 'files=@/path/to/pictures/avatar.jpg&refId=5a993616b8e66660e8baf45c&ref=user&source=users-permissions&field=avatar' http://localhost:1337/upload
```

As you can see is sending image to a specific field. This curl is represented by this JSON:

```
{
  "files": "...", // Buffer or stream of file(s)
  "path": "user/avatar", // Uploading folder of file(s).
  "refId": "5a993616b8e66660e8baf45c", // User's Id.
  "ref": "user", // Model name.
  "source": "users-permissions", // Plugin name.
  "field": "avatar" // Field name in the User model.
}
```

Like this documentation: https://strapi.io/documentation/3.x.x/guides/upload.html#examples

Well, doing it this way in Angular:

Creating an input in the html of my component:

```
<input type="file" name="file" (change)="onFileSelected($event)">
```

Creating your event:

```
onFileSelected(event) {
    console.log(event);
}
```

I have several results among them the file with:

```
files: FileList
0: File(58456)
lastModified: 1542844204930
lastModifiedDate: Wed Nov 21 2018 21:50:04 GMT-0200 (Horário de Verão de Brasília) {}
name: "8.jpg"
size: 58456
type: "image/jpeg"
webkitRelativePath: ""
```

Ok, but make any tests using Postman to understand better who I can do this, return me "true", but nothing happens in my database:

[image]

How can I use the curl, shown at the beginning, with the post-Angled method, or even Postman (which would have a clearer idea), since I already have all the data I need?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to did it with jQuery, you will just have to adapte it with Angular.

You also will have to add your ref attributes to make the relation with your user.

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="file" name="files" id="files">
    <input type="submit" name="" value="Submit">
  </form>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      var data = new FormData();
      $.each($('#files')[0].files, function(i, file) {
        data.append('files', file);
      });

      $.ajax({
        url: '/upload',
        data: data,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        method: 'POST',
        success: function(data){
          alert(data);
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
```